# What is wrong with my .dat file

Tags: c

My code takes a string, writes it in a `.dat` file and then reads it from the `.dat` file and posts it in the console.

My problem is that the `.dat` from what I know should be coded, and I couldn't simply open it and see what's there. But when I open the `d.at` file with notepad, it behaves the same as a `.txt` file and I can see all it's written.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    char s[100],g[100];

    if((f=fopen("text.dat","wb"))==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("write text: "); gets(s);
    int n=strlen(s);
    fwrite(s,sizeof(s[0]),n,f);
    fclose (f);
    if((f=fopen("text.dat","rb"))==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    fread(g,sizeof(g[0]),strlen(s),f);
    puts(g);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A suggestion: try to use `fgets()` instead of using `gets()`

Comment: Why/how should it be "coded" ?

Comment: Post your complete code.  Also, `fread(g,sizeof(g[0]),strlen(s),f);` will not read a NUL-terminated string given the code you *have* posted.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And by "complete" I of course mean with variable declarations.

Comment: As for your problem, the file *is* coded, in whatever encoding you read from the terminal, which is most likely ASCII. That means what you write will *also* be that encoding (i.e. ASCII) which is very readable as plain text.

Comment: A small tip: `sizeof(char)` is implicitly 1, so you don't need to calculate it.

Comment: Ok, i understand. I thought it was always supposed to not be readable when opening it with something like notepad because my last program (which was using arrays) made me a .dat file which looked like this when I opened it with notepad :   >    I and some hiddent characters which I can't copy paste

Comment: Let me guess, it was an array of numerical data, or structures, or something else that wasn't actual text? The `fwrite` function writes out data as it is in memory, and for text it's usually in ASCII (or UTF-8 or similar encoding), while integers and floating point values are stored in their respective encoding.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks !

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst *`sizeof(char)` is implicitly 1* To be (overly?) pedantic, :-), it's explicitly one, per [**6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  *When
`sizeof` is applied to an operand that has type
`char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char`,  (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.*

Comment: Never use `gets()` it was depreciated and in the latest standard is completely removed.   The main problem is it allows the input to overrun the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and leading to a seg fault event.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a single blank line.  2) always follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: in the posted code, before calling `exit()`, the code should let the user know what happened.  Typically the user can be properly informed by calling `perror()` as that will output to stderr the enclosed text and the associated system error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your .dat file.

> My problem is that the .dat from what I know should be coded

What does *coded* mean? Changing a file extension from .txt to .dat doesn't make any difference, in fact it's just renaming it. Microsoft Windows or any other OS may open specific file types with specific programs by default, but that doesn't mean that you can't use the program of your choice.
In this case, notepad will simply read the file contents, which are the characters you read from keyboard and written to it, without any "coding" (except ASCII encoding of course).